# how to fix dependencies while connecting to MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

While connectin to MongoDB server I am getting an error:

> ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use
> mongodb+srv:// URIs. To fix this error install pymongo with the srv
> extra: /opt/conda/bin/python3.10 -m pip install "pymongo[srv]"

Tried uninstalling the and reinstalling pymongo but didn't help , Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

This is the code which I am using:

> from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient uri =
> "mongodb+srv://username:@cluster0.dpveeqd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
>
> Create a new client and connect to the server client =
> MongoClient(uri)
>
> Send a ping to confirm a successful connection try:
> client.admin.command('ping') print("Pinged your deployment. You
> successfully connected to MongoDB!") except Exception as e: print(e)